# Disabling Cast SDK data analytics

Tags: google-play-services, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am currently using Google Cast SDK in my iOS and Android app. I see on iOS that Google Cast SDK collects the following https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/app_privacy but I do not see nutrition facts for Android. What data does Android collect?

I'm wondering if turning off Firebase analytics will turn off cast SDK data collection. For example, if I set `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED` to `YES` on iOS (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios) and `firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated` to `true` on Android, will the cast SDK no longer send this data? If not, is there a way to turn off cast SDK data collection, and how can I test that data is no longer being sent?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to turn off logging/analytics, and there are no plans currently to provide a way to disable logging/analytics. You can find out more information about what Android collects from the GMS Core documentation.

https://issuetracker.google.com/191684320